# Female wizard watching slow-motion snow

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a fantasy short story compilation from my mid-70's middle school. Not sure when it was actually produced. It has a female wizard watching slow-motion snow, other mythical creatures (ogres and such) and a human wanderer that they track and kill by driving a spike through his eye. Anybody else know about this one?